# Cannot turn off bluetooth in Kubuntu 13.04

Tags: bluetooth, 13.04

I have installed a fresh copy of Kubuntu 13.04. In it I could access bluetooth, wireless without any trouble. But I could not turn this off by just pressing the network button on the keyboard. It is always on. Since I am new to Kubuntu I don't know how to figure this out.

Answer (score 2):

Disable Bluetooth on startup

Source : [Is there a power saving application similar to Jupiter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/jupiter-or-similar-app-for-13-04/285681#285681)

```
 sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

And add the following line before exit 0

```
 rfkill block bluetooth
```

**Save & Exit & Reboot**

Your bluetooth is off on startup but you can enable it from bluetooth icon.

**Note**: Some time my bluetooth icon is showing its on, but actually its turn off, I have check it many time

I can verify that its off by

```
 sudo tlp-stat
```

Wireless Section

```
 +++ Wireless
 bluetooth = off (software)
 wifi      = on
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, but I don't even know how to save in terminal (Konsol)

Comment: @ThuwarakeshMurallie use > sudo gedit /etc/rc.local > and then you can save it

Answer (score 1):

***Disable Bluetooth*** (and some other services) from **starting up**

Solution involves use of **inbuilt Graphical tool** "*Startup Applications*". The process involves merely "un-ticking" the relevant services. Thus its a simple and intuitive solution.

This works under Ubuntu 12.10 and should work in 13.04 too, provided the "Startup Application" tool is present in 13.04.

**Step 1**- Open the tool by typing "Startup Application" in the **Dash** and clicking on the tool icon. (I hope this tool exists in 13.04 version)
-- *Accessing* Dash-(there may be other ways too)
 1) Press Winkey once
 2) OR In the quick launch bar, click the first icon.

**Step 2**- From amongst the listed services, *un-tick* the Bluetooth service.
(Other services can be turned off too, but you should be aware of the consequences)

Now close the tool..that all. The settings would apply next time you restart the OS.

**Note:** One **advantage** of disabling services is to free up the RAM and processor load but the **downside** is that if you require these services, you need to enable them manually.